# What is the intersection of row space and column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> What is the intersection of row space and column space ?

I calculated the row space and the column space of the matrix below
(first the column space then I transposed it to find out the row space ), and got row rank $=2=$ column rank , but what is meant with the intersection of it, in both cases the first and the second vector give a basis, but I don't know how to proceed

[image: column space]

[image]

Comment: In the link does not appear any square matrix, so your question is incomplete, or it does not make sense.

Comment: @Crostul I took a screenshot of them

Comment: Your matrix is not square, so column space and row space live into two different worlds (row space $\subseteq \Bbb{R}^4$ while column space $\subseteq \Bbb{R}^3$), which are disjoint. So the intersection is empty.

Comment: @Crostul what if it were square, how do I continue then ?

Comment: If your matrix is square, then you have two subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^n$, say $R$ (generated by rows) and $C$ (generated by columns). So $R \cap C$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$. Although, computing the intersection of two subspaces is not an easy problem.